# How do I display leading zeros on a number in SAS?

Tags: sas

Currently, I have a data, including upc code. The value in UPC code is ranged from 3 digits to 5 digits. Thus, I want to unify all these upc codes with 5 digits.

For example, upc code is 111. I would make this value as 00111. How can I do this in sas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `zw.d` format.

```
data have;
 upc=111;
run;

data want;
 set have;
 upc_char = put(upc,z5.);
run;
```

If `upc` is a character variable to start with, you need `input` along with `put`.