# create a key field in a table of the same length in sas

Tags: sas, key

I have a key field in a `SAS` table that is a sequential number. I want to create a key with that number but with some zeros first of the number, so that all the items of the key have length=15.

can someone help?

thanks

Comment: Kind of a dublicate. Have a look e.g. at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963623/how-do-i-display-leading-zeros-on-a-number-in-sas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `z.` format:

```
charackterKey = put(numericKey,z15.);
```